# Python Dictionary: Unsupported operand types for + ("object" and "int") from Mypy

Tags: python, mypy

I have a dictionary that takes the following default value:

```py
context = {
    'a': {'a_sub': 0}
    'b': 1
}

# Somewhere else in the code, b is iterated
context['b'] += 1
```

The project has pre-commit setup with Mypy, it gives the following error:

```
Unsupported operand types for + ("object" and "int")
```

Edit: The error went away if `a`'s type is also `int`, i.e.

```py
context = {
    'a': 0,
    'b': 1
}
context['b'] += 1  # Mypy is happy about this
```

So it seems Mypy think the value of the key can be either int or a dict/object, which is why it is complaining.

Any idea how to fix this ? The context dictionary should expect key-value of any type, and `b` is expected to be int.

Thanks

Comment: somewhere in your code you have redefined `context` or the value of `context['b']` so it's no longer an int. Check in your code where else you use context and you will see that at some point you assign a value that is not an int.

Comment: dictionaries (to be precise, `dict`) don't work like that. There's one key type and one value type. If two values have different types, the common supertype will be used. Here that's `object`, and you can't add an `object` and an `int`. If you want each key to have a different type, consider a `dataclass`, or if you must use a dict, a `TypedDict`

Comment: @joel . Thanks.. That makes sense. But code wide this is not illegal. For example it is common to parse a json into dict with different types. So I wonder whether it still has much merit to follow the 1 key type 1 value type rule. ? What is your view on this.

Comment: @joel, I see you added the `TypedDict` option and PEP589. So it seems that is the better way to go. Please submit your answer if you want

Comment: It's legal Python, but there are *lots* of more specific types than `dict[str, Any]` that could describe `context`, so no one is going to try to guess which one it is. The point of static typing is to ensure that `context['b'] += 1` is valid, not to assume that it is valid and make up types to support that assumption.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes exactly. joel also mentioned about TypedDict and PEP589. Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for explanation. After learning about `TypedDict` it is now clear.

Comment: when i said "one key type and one value type", i meant static types, not runtime types. Of course you can stick whatever you want in your `dict`